# insert markdown for bold and italics around selection

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

I am making an application that uses markdown to format text. I need to add keyboard shortcuts, so that people that do not know how to use markdown and are more familiar with WYSIWYG editors are able to use it. How would I do that?

Comment: You can't unfortunately enter specific html elements inside an `<input>` element. Probably the closest workaround is to use a `<textarea>` instead

Comment: @Rawrplus it’s already a textarea:   `<p class="w3-large">Editor</p>
            <textarea style="min-height:200px;" id="msginput" class="w3-input" oninput='this.style.height = "";this.style.height = this.scrollHeight + 3 + "px"'></textarea>` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is just the extended version of the function given by @CcJokerPol.

**Additional Features:**

- This adds `text` as well as removes too.
- it allows adding a default text too.
- Snippet shows to call the function using `ctrl+b`, `ctrl+i`, `ctrl+u` too.
- Multiple markdowns can also be added like as `**++underlined bold text++**`

**Example:**

- a text to `bold` => a text to `**bold**`
- a text to remove **`bold`** => a text to remove `bold`
- a text to remove `**bold**` => a text to remove `bold`

Calling is the same `insertFormating(inputBox, "**", "bold");`

```js
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
 if (e.ctrlKey && $.inArray(e.keyCode, [66, 73, 85, 76]) > -1) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  var focused = document.activeElement;
  var id = focused.id;
    e.preventDefault();
    if (keyCode == 66) {
      insertFormating(focused, "**", "bold");
    } else if (keyCode == 73) {
      insertFormating(focused, "__", "italic");
    } else if (keyCode == 85) {
      insertFormating(focused, "++", "underline");
    } else if (keyCode == 76) {
      insertFormating(focused, "[", "link title", "](http://www.example.com)");
    }
 }
});

function insertFormating(txtarea, text, defaultTxt = "", text2 = "") {
 var selectStart = txtarea.selectionStart
 var selectEnd = txtarea.selectionEnd
 var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
 var caretPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
 var mode = 0; //Adding markdown with selected text
 var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, caretPos);
 var back = (txtarea.value).substring(selectEnd, txtarea.value.length);
 var middle = (txtarea.value).substring(caretPos, selectEnd);

 if (text2 == "") {
  text2 = text;
 }
 var textLen = text.length;
 var text2Len = text2.length;

 if (selectStart === selectEnd) {
  middle = defaultTxt;
  mode = 1; //Adding markdown with default text
 } else {
  if (front.substr(-textLen) == text && back.substr(0, text2Len) == text2) {
   front = front.substring(0, front.length - textLen);
   back = back.substring(text2Len, back.length);
   text = "";
   text2 = "";
   mode = 2; //Removing markdown with selected text eg. **<selected>bold<selected>**
  } else if (middle.substr(0, textLen) == text && middle.substr(-text2Len) == text2) {
   middle = middle.substring(textLen, middle.length - text2Len);
   text = "";
   text2 = "";
   mode = 3; //Removing markdown with selected text eg. <selected>**bold**<selected>
  }
 }
 txtarea.value = front + text + middle + text2 + back;
 if (selectStart !== selectEnd) {
  if (mode === 0) {
   txtarea.selectionStart = selectStart + textLen;
   txtarea.selectionEnd = selectEnd + textLen;
  } else if (mode === 2) {
   txtarea.selectionStart = selectStart - textLen;
   txtarea.selectionEnd = selectEnd - textLen;
  } else if (mode === 3) {
   txtarea.selectionStart = selectStart;
   txtarea.selectionEnd = selectEnd - textLen - text2Len;
  }
 } else {
  txtarea.selectionStart = selectStart + textLen;
  txtarea.selectionEnd = txtarea.selectionStart + middle.length;
 }
 txtarea.focus();
 txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="5" cols="60">A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Test it here.</textarea>
```

---

**Shortcut commands used in snippet:**

- `ctrl+b` => Bold => `**bold text**`
- `ctrl+i` => Italic => `__italic text__`
- `ctrl+u` => Underline => `++underlined text++`
- `ctrl+l` => Link => `[link title](http://www.example.com)`

---

### Update:

- Now you can add different beginning and closing markdown tags
- **eg.** `insertFormating(focused, "[", "link title","](http://www.example.com)");`

Answer (score 3):

this function uses `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` along with substring to insert text before and after the selected text.

```
async function insertFormating(txtarea, text) {
    var selectStart = txtarea.selectionStart
    var selectEnd = txtarea.selectionEnd
    var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
    var caretPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

    var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, caretPos);
    var back = (txtarea.value).substring(txtarea.selectionEnd, txtarea.value.length);
    var middle = (txtarea.value).substring(caretPos, txtarea.selectionEnd);
    txtarea.value = front + text + middle + text + back;
    if (selectStart !== selectEnd) {
        txtarea.selectionStart = selectStart + text.length
        txtarea.selectionEnd = selectEnd + text.length
    } else {
        txtarea.selectionStart = selectStart + text.length
        txtarea.selectionEnd = txtarea.selectionStart
    }
    txtarea.focus();
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}
```

you can now call `insertFormating(inputBox, '**');` to insert bold, or `insertFormating(inputBox, '_');` for italics.